# How do I output the marks in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

When I try to display the marks, BlueJ keeps returning java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
for (index = 0; index < assignmentLimit; index++)
    {  
        System.out.println("\nAssigment " + (index + 1) + " marks:");
        for (indexTwo = 0; indexTwo < studentLimit; indexTwo++)
        {
            System.out.print("\nMark " + (indexTwo + 1) + ": ");
            String input = console.readLine();
            mark[grade][indexTwo] = Integer.parseInt(input);
        }
    }
System.out.print("\n\t" + mark[grade][indexTwo]);
```

Comment: Consider upgrading to a real IDE and using a debugger. Alternatively, use pen and paper to trace execution.

Comment: I have to use BlueJ because that's what my school makes me use.

Comment: (Test your code in a proper IDE and copy it over to BlueJ when it's correct.)

Comment: Also, read up on what a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` _is_. Java has a documentation feature called Javadoc.

Comment: What's the variable grade and studentLimit? Most probably the problem lies with your loop exceeded your array bound.

Comment: grade is the student's grade on the assignment. studentLimit is the number of students.

Answer (score 0):

Since you iterate `index` first, and then `indexTwo`, I guess you really want to do this instead:

```
mark[index][indexTwo] = Integer.parseInt(input);
```